# Objective C - Apple Mach - O Linker Error

Tags: ios, cordova, linker, xcode5, phonegap-plugins

I'm using social sharing phonegap plugin for my mobile app project. I got this problem when build the project. I got a several of error. I'm using this phonegap plugin for my social sharing function. Check https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_SLServiceTypeTwitter", referenced from:
      -[SocialSharing shareViaTwitter:] in SocialSharing.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMessageComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SocialSharing.o
  "_SLServiceTypeFacebook", referenced from:
      -[SocialSharing shareViaFacebook:] in SocialSharing.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SocialSharing.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why?

Comment: Did you add Social.framework?

Comment: You are probably missing frameworks. Try adding Message/MessageUI/Social frameworks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the frame works by using the following steps:

1. In the project navigator, select your project
2. Select your target
3. Select the 'Build Phases' tab
4. Open 'Link Binaries With Libraries' expander
5. Click the '+' button
6. Select framework (`MessageUI.framework` and `Social.framework` in your case)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as well, and I followed the steps mentioned here:
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/issues/116

So, basically I remove the platform:

`cordova platform remove ios`

Then add it back:

`cordova platform add ios`

Hope it helps!